# I'm trying to install screen on GCE vm but it says permission denied

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

can anyone help me here? It will be very helpful if you can
 apt-get update 
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?

Comment: Hell and Welcome to stackoverflow, your question lacks important information, please look to [ask] and edit the aformentioned question.

Comment: Though I don't quite understand the question, but I guess -- Missing `sudo`

Answer (score 1):

These commands should be done by a root user. Try using `sudo` before running the commands.